# Is it possible to use NSZombieEnabled in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, nszombie

I've been reading up about the environmental variable [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) and I wondered whether it is currently possible to use this in a Monotouch runtime? If not, is there a suitable alternative that I'm just glazing over?

<strike>The reason I ask is because it may be helpful to find any leaks one may have in their app - I've tried to use Instruments with limited success and would like to try every possible option to ensure I have a nice and stable app.</strike>

**Edit**

I misunderstood what they were used for (it is Monday morning after all...) - but I would still be curious to know whether it is possible, or because of C#'s automated GC, whether they would be relevant?

Comment: NSZombies won't help you finding leaks. It helps you debugging crashes caused by over releasing. Leaks are the opposite of this.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood what they did - thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch automatically enables NSZombieEnabled when running on the simulator debugger.

There is currently no way to enable this on the device.