# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) crash

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crash-reports

My app keeps crashing at random whilst on device and I'm lost in the depths of mono trying to find the cause. I've got one of the crash logs off the device and symbolicated the crash logs but am none the wiser as to what is going on.

```
Incident Identifier: C08DE68B-8F34-4890-B98F-82E419AE22B8
CrashReporter Key:   4366a5c0e38fe77ba2472a4965721c1dcf116cbd
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:             TestingApp [802]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7CBC009C-4304-4F45-9244-AA668F346513/TestingApp.app/TestingApp
Identifier:          com.testing.TestingApp
Version:             50021 (0.4.3)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-12 18:45:06.06 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-10-12 18:41:31.31 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.0 (13A344)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0163bdf9
Triggered by Thread:  15

Filtered syslog:
None found
```

Thread 15 is:

```
Thread 15 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34709d24 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x347ad74a pthread_kill + 62
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x346a1f40 abort + 108
3   TestingApp                      0x00fd2398 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2386)
4   TestingApp                      0x00fdbfe4 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini.c:6820)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x347a7076 _sigtramp + 42
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x34731dee szone_malloc_should_clear + 1198
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33ef5982 lookUpImpOrForward + 158
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33ef58da _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33efbd5a _objc_msgSend_uncached + 26
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33f093a8 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 388
11  CoreFoundation                  0x22619fa8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
12  Foundation                      0x233fe9f8 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 120
13  TestingApp                      0x0108efb4 xamarin_thread_finish(void*) (shared.m:199)
14  TestingApp                      0x0108ecd0 thread_end(_MonoProfiler*, unsigned long) (shared.m:211)
15  TestingApp                      0x01031faa mono_profiler_thread_end (profiler.c:586)
16  TestingApp                      0x010614b2 async_invoke_thread (threadpool.c:1716)
17  TestingApp                      0x01068224 start_wrapper (threads.c:593)
18  TestingApp                      0x01080cfa inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x347ac872 _pthread_body + 138
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x347ac7e6 _pthread_start + 110
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x347aa740 thread_start + 8
```

When connected through Xamarin studio debugger the app still randomly crashes however the debugger doesn't report anything. I've also set it the break on all System.Exception but again don't hit anything. How do I approach trying to find what my issue is?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is telling you that a native object (i.e. NSObject..) is being accessed after it has been deallocated. You can enable NSZombieEnabled via mtouch's ` --debugtrack` and using Xcode's console log you will see an item like 'message sent to deallocated instance' that is preceded by the object type...

Comment: I thought it [wasn't possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923738/596239) to enable NSZombieEnabled on device builds in Xamarin or has this changed?