# Xamarin: Apple Rejection : We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

We have tested it on AdHoc build and TestFlight Internal Testing but it don't replicate the crash experience from Apple Review. We are using:

xCode 8.3.3
Visual Studio 7.0.1
Xamarin Studio 6.3
Latest Updates Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin Forms

Any Idea about this logs or is it bug on xamarin?

> Apple Rejection:
>
> 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> **> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
>   attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.**
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device
>   to ensure it will launch without crashing.

CRASH LOGS SENT FROM ITUNES REJECTION

```
{"app_name":"GuardiansAppiOS","timestamp":"2017-07-27 07:09:54.08 -0700","app_version":"1.3.13","slice_uuid":"{UUID}","adam_id":1214197075,"build_version":"1.147","bundleID":"com.guardiansaps.app","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)","incident_id":"{ID}"{","name":"GuardiansAppiOS"}
Incident Identifier: {ID}
CrashReporter Key:   1c09fd6d991ad4628cb086935d31af33e2120112
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             GuardiansAppiOS [1428]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/{Path}/GuardiansAppiOS.app/GuardiansAppiOS
Identifier:          {package name}
Version:             1.147 (1.3.13)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           {package name} [1099]


Date/Time:           2017-07-27 07:09:53.9535 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-07-27 07:09:53.5772 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018cb31014 0x18cb12000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018cbfb264 0x18cbf6000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018caa59c4 0x18ca44000 + 399812
3   GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101acb03c 0x10005c000 + 27717692
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018cbf531c 0x18cbef000 + 25372
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018cbfb264 0x18cbf6000 + 21092
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018caa59c4 0x18ca44000 + 399812
7   GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101bcb0b8 0x10005c000 + 28766392
8   GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101b06994 0x10005c000 + 27961748
9   GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101acac54 0x10005c000 + 27716692
10  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101ac9c78 0x10005c000 + 27712632
11  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101ac29c0 0x10005c000 + 27683264
12  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x000000010150b774 0x10005c000 + 21690228
13  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x000000010148f684 0x10005c000 + 21182084
14  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x000000010006b5dc 0x10005c000 + 62940
15  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000100100f84 0x10005c000 + 675716
16  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101ad827c 0x10005c000 + 27771516
17  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101b3d0dc 0x10005c000 + 28184796
18  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x0000000101b3d038 0x10005c000 + 28184632
19  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x00000001016bb6d0 0x10005c000 + 23459536
20  GuardiansAppiOS                 0x00000001016bbc6c 0x10005c000 + 23460972
21  UIKit                           0x0000000193cd2e48 0x193c52000 + 527944
22  UIKit                           0x0000000193edf37c 0x193c52000 + 2675580
23  UIKit                           0x0000000193ee4e24 0x193c52000 + 2698788
24  UIKit                           0x0000000193ef98b0 0x193c52000 + 2783408
25  UIKit                           0x0000000193ee20b8 0x193c52000 + 2687160
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f6e0884 0x18f6a6000 + 239748
```

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` *almost* always means a null exception, but symbolicate the crash log that Apple sent you and determine where the problem is in your code.

Comment: According to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099483/how-to-debug-exc-bad-access-sigabrt-crash You need to enable Zombie.

Comment: Are you testing on the same OS as Apple? `iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)`

Comment: Yes symbolicate the crash log is the best way to see crash. . thanks for the answer.. we'll try it..

Comment: yes we also use iPhone 10.3.3 @william

Comment: thanks Sérgio we'll try also the zombie enable..